# How can I create a Binary Search Tree with Linked Lists on every node?

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm trying to create a Binary Search Tree with Linked Lists on every node, something like the picture but the blue arrows are not desired. I'm currently using `tikz-qtree` to create my trees.

Current tree:

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={minimum width=2em,draw,circle},
     blank/.style={draw=none},
     edge from parent/.style=
     {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
     level distance=1.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree
  [.2,1
    [.1,2
      [.0,2
        \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{};
        [.0,3
          \edge[blank]; \node[blank]{};
          [.0,4 ]
        ]
      ]
      [.1,4 ]
    ]
    [.2,2 ]
  ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: BST with linked list]

Comment: I can draw simple tree, but I don't know how I can add a linked list to a node. I posted the current tree code. BST means binary search tree.

Comment: the shown tree does not look like a BST (binary Search Tree) to me. more like a left shifted disfigured tree. maybe if you could clearify you intentions, the community could provide better help.

Comment: I don't understand how I can be more specific, I would like that my tree have a linked list starting from every node, just like the picture below. 

What is the problem with the tree? It is a not balanced binary search tree using two key for comparison.

Comment: You can just use Ti*k*Z to add the list nodes since you're using `tikz-qtree`. I'd use Forest, but that's because I like it and could probably automate it so Forest placed all or most of the list nodes for me. `tikz-qtree` doesn't have the same power, but you can use the full power of Ti*k*Z to do the job.

Comment: In any case, please provide complete code. How is `blank` defined? Presumably you are loading `tikz-qtree`? Anything else needed for the example? (Or does `tikz-qtree` define`blank`?)

Comment: I forgot the tikzset command, it is user defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. This solution defines a `forest` style `binary search tree`.

For each node within the tree, it is possible to typeset a second node to the right or left, to contain the list. If this is desired, the content of the node should be specified in the form

```
<content of main node>:<content of secondary node>
```

Because the contents of all nodes include commas in this case, the form

```
{<content of main node>}:{<content of secondary node>}
```

is needed. Translating your code and adding some secondary nodes, for example,

```
\begin{forest}
  binary search tree,
  [{2,1}:{1,1}
    [{1,2}:{0,1}
      [{0,2}:{2,2}
        [,phantom]
        [{0,3}:{1,4}
          [,phantom]
          [{0,4}:{-3,0}]
        ]
      ]
      [{1,4}:{0,-1}]
    ]
    [{2,2}:{-1,1}]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: binary search tree]

You said that the blue/green arrows were not required, so I've left the tree plain. However, these could easily be added using the `tikz` or `tikz+` keys, if desired.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  list me/.style={draw, no edge},
  list node/.style={%
    if level=0{%
      label={[draw, anchor=east, label distance=5pt]left:{#1}},
    }{%
      if n=1{%
        insert before={[{#1}, list me]},
      }{%
        if={strequal((content("!u1")),"")}{%
          for nodewalk={fake=u,n=1}{%
            insert before={[{#1},phantom]},
          },
        }{},
        insert after={[{#1}, list me]},
      },
    },
  },
  binary search tree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      circle,
      draw,
    },
    delay={%
      for tree={%
        split option={content}{:}{content,list node},
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where content={}{%
        if nodewalk valid={s}{%
          content/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{content("!s")},
        }{},
      }{},
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  binary search tree,
  [{2,1}:{1,1}
    [{1,2}:{0,1}
      [{0,2}:{2,2}
        [,phantom]
        [{0,3}:{1,4}
          [,phantom]
          [{0,4}:{-3,0}]
        ]
      ]
      [{1,4}:{0,-1}]
    ]
    [{2,2}:{-1,1}]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```